# How to install script in atom after sunsetting of atom, if possible?

Tags: text, scripting, editor, atom-editor

I used to run: `apm install script` from the terminal before : [sunsetting](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/) of `atom` text editor. The command now produces the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
    at /snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/lib/install.js:256:29
    at Request._callback (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/lib/request.js:57:22)
    at Request.self.callback (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
```

From what I understood, atom organization has archived everything before sunset. Is there still a way to install `script` and still use `atom`, or it has to be forgotten now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With atom, atom-beta, and atom-dev this is not possible (`apm`, `apm-beta`, and `apm-dev`).

You would need to install pulsar-edit, and then use the `ppm` command to install `script` from the mirrored repository. Note that pulsar-edit and ppm both have not stabilized yet and are still in beta (and so your results may vary on the behavior of the package post-install), but this is the only current method to install the `script` package:

- install pulsar-edit
- `ppm install script`

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but by introducing a brand new pulsar! Can you just replace ```scripts``` by ```script``` in your answer, I had started this mistake! Thanks anyway.